# Is Bloc pattern appropriate to manage navigation in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

I'm asking if bloc_flutter (Bloc pattern implementation for flutter), is the right solution to manage the app "navigation".

I used bloc_flutter to manage firebase login https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login.

After user successfully loggedin, he lands in a "welcome screen" with menu. I tried to manage screen navigation of this menu, using a new bloc pattern but it seems an overwhelming solution to me.
Moreover, using navigation with bloc pattern doesn't let you use Android "back button".

So, would be better, in your opinion, using navigation of routes and let bloc manages the logic of each screen?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. If you want your application to have a good architecture, you should not use bloc in order to handle navigation since navigation is not something related to the application's business logic, it's a part of the UI.

Comment: Then what would you suggest ? Example: User loggs in and you want to navigate to a new page. With a "AuthorizationBloc" is quite simple to do, you listen to "LoggedIn" event and navigate with globalNavigatorKey. The alternative would be to dispatch a new state and show a different screen in the ui but that is not a navigation to a new page and won't trigger page screen change and tracking

Answer (score 0):

I pass `GlobalKey<NavigatorState>` to bloc and can perform navigation from there:

```dart
  @override
  Stream<MyScreenState> mapEventToState(
    MyScreenEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SomeEvent) {
      _navigatorKey.currentState.push(...);
    }
  }
```

Note that this key needs to be used on `MaterialApp` instantiation to get things working:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But question is: is using BloC worth it for navigation or not?